# PHP SOAP default namespace for client requests

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I have a working SOAP server described by the WSDL file : http://pastebin.com/YXBbszqE.
However, the problem is that a remote client sends messages in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <soap12:Body>
  <Query>
   <request>
    <MerchantNumber>7436</MerchantNumber>
    <RestoCode>9999</RestoCode>
    <WaiterID>1</WaiterID>
    <FolioInfo>
     <FolioType>FolioTypeCard</FolioType>
     <Folio>1234124234123123</Folio>
    </FolioInfo>
   </request>
  </Query>
 </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

which is rejected by my server with the following error message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
 <env:Body>
  <env:Fault>
   <env:Code>
    <env:Value>rpc:ProcedureNotPresent</env:Value>
   </env:Code>
   <env:Reason>
    <env:Text>Procedure not present</env:Text>
   </env:Reason>
  </env:Fault>
 </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I did some debugging and found what the problem is, but I don't know how to solve this. A valid SOAP request would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://MD.org/">
 <soap12:Body>
  <ns1:Query>
   <request>
    <MerchantNumber>7436</MerchantNumber>
    <RestoCode>9999</RestoCode>
    <WaiterID>1</WaiterID>
    <FolioInfo>
     <FolioType>FolioTypeCard</FolioType>
     <Folio>1234124234123123</Folio>
    </FolioInfo>
   </request>
  </ns1:Query>
 </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

which responds fine. Notice the **xmlns:ns1="http://MD.org/"** in the header and the **ns1:** on the Query tag.

Is there a way for my server to know what namespace it is when a request comes through?

Thank you, your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to modify the client's request on the server side before actually running any code.

Comment: another possible solution may be to tell the soap server to completely ignore namespaces, is it possible?

Comment: I've never had to set namespaces on my requests before (AFAIK)...

Comment: yep , apparently after a software update of the application soap requests now HAVE the namespace mentioned. mmyeah....
thank you all for your help

Comment: For people finding this in the future and having similar issues when e.g. writing clients: `elementFormDefault="qualified"` from WSDL wasn't obeyed.